# Sulle preposizioni “a” e “in”

Tags: prepositions

Di solito i complementi di luogo richiedono la preposizione "in" ma se si tratta di un luogo abituale (da non essere considerato luogo fisico) si usa "a". Ecco degli esempi: Vado al bar, ma Vado IN un bar, IN che bar vai? Bar in cui vai.

Ci sono però casi in cui si usa "a" in tutti i contesti (sia in una domanda, affermazione con articolo indeterminativo/determinativo e frase relativa)... con parole come "festa" o "tavolo": Vado alla festa, ad una festa, festa a cui vado, a quale festa vai?  a quale tavolo ti siedi/vai? Il tavolo al quale vado/mi siedo? Sono seduto ad un tavolo.

Però molto  spesso  ci sono dei casi un pò ingarbugliati... per esempio: 
 Si dice "a quale fermata vai/ti trovi/scendi" 
 " mi trovo/vado/scendo a questa/una fermata" 
 Ma se dobbiamo relativizzare bisogna usare "in cui": 
La fermata in cui/vado/scendo/mi fermo/sono ecc...

Con piano la situazione è ancora più complicata: 
" A che piano/abiti/scendi/ti fermi?" 
"Mi trovo/vado/fermo al primo piano" 
Ma negli altri casi si usa in: 
" mi sono fermato/sono andato/abito in un piano che si trova in questo palazzo" 
"Il piano in cui abito/scendo ecc"

Vorrei un attimo capire come fare per non sbagliare preposizione... mi trovo molto in difficoltà

Comment: «se dobbiamo relativizzare bisogna usare "in cui": La fermata in cui/vado/scendo/mi fermo/sono ecc...»: non direi proprio; e non direi nemmeno “in un piano” etc. Dove hai sentito cose del genere?

Comment: Quindi bisogna usare a cui?  Per esempio: "questa/questo è la/il fermata/piano a cui vado/scendo/mi fermo/ mi trovo"  "abito/scendo/mi fermo ad un piano/fermata tra il/la quinto e il/la sesto piano/fermata"   "

Comment: Con tutte le barre non sono sicuro di capire bene, ma sì, io direi senz'altro “questa è la fermata a cui scendo” etc.

Comment: Il problema è che per questa tua domanda, come per l'altra su questo argomento, è pressoché impossibile una risposta completa, se non su casi specifici. Non è possibile descrivere compiutamente le regole per l'uso di “a” e “in” perché sono più le eccezioni che le regolarità (pensa solo ai nomi di nazioni: “in Germania”, “a Cuba”, “negli Stati Uniti”...), senza contare la varietà tra i parlanti (in certe parti d'Italia si preferisce “a” con i nomi di strade, in altre “in”: “a/in via Nazionale”).

Comment: Provo a riscrivere le frasi in modo comprensibile:                1)Questa è la fermata a cui vado/scendo/mi trovo.         2)Scendo/vado/mi trovo a questa fermata                    
 3) questo è il piano a cui vado/scendo/abito                        4)abito/scendo/vado a questo piano che ti sto indicando... Spero che adesso possa darmi una risposta più precisa se c'è qualcosa di sbagliato

Comment: @Nakamura: La mia raccomandazione sarebbe di scrivere domande non tanto generali, ma molto più concrete.